# recorrer un diccionario y una lista de forma simultanea de forma re cursiva en python

Tags: python-3.7

tengo varias semanas en esto sin éxito el objetivo es por medio de la lista recorer el diccionario o comprobar  hasta que salga el mensaje you lose , you win o klk que se encuentra al final del diccionario usando solo los elementos de la lista

```py
dic = {  
  'a':{ 'b': {'c': 'You win'}},
  'x':{ 'y':{'z': 'You lose'}},
  'r':{ 'q':{'s': 'Klk manin'}}
}

a = ['x','y','z']

dic1 = dic['x']
dic2 = dic1['y']
dic3 = dic2['z']
print(dic3)
```

gracias de antemano

Comment: En el título dices "de forma recursiva". ¿Es eso un requisito o era solo una forma de hablar? Es decir ¿la función que lo resuelva debe hacerlo llamándose a sí misma?

Answer (score 0):

Segun entiendo quieres recorrer un diccionario en base a una lista de llaves, y retornar el valor resultante de la cadena de indexación de llaves al diccionario.

```
dic = {  
  'a':{ 'b': {'c': 'You win'}},
  'x':{ 'y':{'z': 'You lose'}},
  'r':{ 'q':{'s': 'Klk manin'}}
}

a = ['x','y','z']

def key_list_indexing(key_list, dic):
    curr_dic = dic
    for key in key_list:
        curr_dic = dic[key]
    return curr_dic


print(key_list_indexing(a, dic))
# imrpime 'you lose'
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar la recursividad

```
dic = {  
  'a':{ 'b': {'c': 'You win'}},
  'x':{ 'y':{'z': 'You lose'}},
  'r':{ 'q':{'s': 'Klk manin'}}
}

def iterate(dict_to_iterate) :
    for key, value in dict_to_iterate.items() :
        if isinstance(value, dict) :
            iterate(value)
        else :
            print(value)


iterate(dic)
```

básicamente lo que se hace es revisar si es un diccionario, si lo es, se usa la misma función hasta que sea un texto, [Aquí](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=recursividad%20en%20python&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) puedes saber más sobre funciones repulsivas en python